# Java - write text to the remote file

Tags: java

I try to get txt file from server and write some text to it. But it seems that method I'm using doesn't work.

```
 public static void writeFile(String urls, String text) throws Exception {

    String string = URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");

    URL url = new URL(urls);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                                     connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write(string);
    out.append("a");
    out.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(
                                connection.getInputStream()));
    String decodedString;
    while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(decodedString);
    }
    in.close();     
}
```

I run it like this:

```
    try {
        writeFile("http://myserver.com/notes.txt", "testing massage");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Please help me. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Please provide more information about the actual problem.  Your "*doesn't work*"  is not informative enough.

Comment: You must have the target server awaiting a HTTP request, processing it, and writing the file. There is no way to directly write a file remotely on a HTTP location, like what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Tomas As Berger Says have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Comment: @SanKrish I have red this instruction and made this code relying on this tutorial. Addionally, I set 777 chmod to notes.txt file. But it doesn't help me. Should I do something from the server-side?